# How does css loader resolve resources in webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, webpack-loader

I was learning about css-loader in webpack, the defination says that

The css-loader interprets `@import` and `url()` like `import/require()`and will resolve them. What does it mean, In an example in the documentaion there is

> `url(image.png) => require('./image.png')`

So my question is  will it convert `url('./image.png')` to  `require('image.png')`

For example in a css file if i have background property as

```
#selector{
   background:url('./image.png'); //this is a vlid css property
}
```

will the above style converted like

```
#selector{
   background:require('./image.png'); // this is not a valid css property
}
```

if this is how the conversion take place than `background:require('./image.png')` is not valid css,
is there something wrong in my understanding, may be i'm not getting what css-loader does actually. I went through the documentation of css-loader.

can anyone explain where i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

please read about css-loader resolve urls
https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#url

if its just about understanding, webpack is fully js based. that means there have to be a way to check does the file exist, copy file or step in further actions. in the endfile it's simply css syntax with 'replaced/resolved' URL.

```
background:url('wp-content/themes/yours/assets/image.png');
```

check also
https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader

Comment: What this lines, The css-loader interprets @import and url() like import/require() and will resolve them

Comment: import/require is way to load files in js. webpack is written in js. everything you will import in webpack will be loaded/resolved by webpack because thats necessary for bundling. you load css, so the urls have to be resolved for js to write it back in css with the correct path.

Comment: so will css-loader convert url() into require(),and then webpack resolve the require statement,This is how it will work