# useEffect inside custom hook not getting called in correct oreder in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i am using `useEffect` inside a custom hook called `useCustomHook`, i am using this `useCustomHook` in two component i.e (First,Second),but`useEffect` getting called only when the `First` and `Second` component get's rendered.

For example

I have a First component

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import useCustomHook from './customHook'

function First(){
 console.log("component First rendering")
 const [count,setCount]=useState(0)
 useCustomHook(count)

 return (<div>First component</div>)

}
```

This is my Second component

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import useCustomHook from './customHook'

function Second(){
 console.log("component Second rendering")
 const [count,setCount]=useState(0)
 useCustomHook(count)

 return (<div>Second component</div>)

}
```

And this is my customHook

```
import {useEffect} from 'react'

function useCustomHook(count){
  console.log("useCustomHook getting called")
  useEffect(()=>{
 console.log("useEffect gets called") //this function is running after both component rendered
  },[count])

}
```

My main App component

```
import First from './first'
import Second from './second'

function App(){
   return (
      <div>
        <First/>
        <Second/>
      </div>
    )
}
```

**My console output is :**

1) component First rendering

2) useCustomHook getting called

3) component Second rendering

4) useCustomHook getting called

5) (2) useEffect gets called

**I want to know**

Why is the line `5` output is not after the line `2`, Why is `Second` component log is happening after line `2`, because `useEffect` should be called after the `useCustomHook` being called by the `First` component but before that `Second` component log is called. why is `useEffect` inside `useCustomHook` not getting called before `Second` component log.

Comment: use ```useLayoutEffect``` to get desired result. ```useEffect``` triggers after first render

Comment: No I just want to know why is this behaviour happening with useEffect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your output is as it should be.

I think you are confused about the output because you think that `useEffect` is same as `componentDidMount` but that is not correct. They both are different, couple of important differences between them are mentioned below:

### They run at different times

(related to your question)

They both are called after the initial render of the component but `useEffect` is called **after** the browser has painted the screen whereas `componentDidMount` is called **before** the screen is painted by the browser.

### Capturing props and state

(not related to your question, feel free to skip to the end of the answer)

`useEffect` captures the state and props whereas `componentDidMount` doesn't do this.

Consider the following code snippets to understand what *useEffect captures the state and props* means.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('count value = ' + this.state.count);
    }, 4000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>You clicked the button { this.state.count } times</p>
        <button
          onClick={ () => this.setState(prev => ({ count: prev.count + 1 })) }>
          Increment Counter
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

```js
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('count value = ' + count);
    }, 4000);
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked the button { count } times</p>
      <button
        onClick={ () => setCount(count + 1) }>
        Increment Counter
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Both code snippets are same except first one has class based component and second one has functional component.

These both snippets have a variable named `count` in the state and they both log the value of the `count` variable to the console after 4 seconds. They also include a button which can be used to increment the value of the `count`.

Try to click the button (4 or 5 times) before the value of the `count` is logged on the console.

If you thought that `componentDidMount` and `useEffect` are same then you might be surprised to see that both code snippets log different values of `count` variable after 4 seconds.

Class based code snippet logs the latest value whereas functional component based code snippet logs the initial value of `count` variable.

Reason why they log different value of `count` variable is because:

- `this.state` inside class component always points to latest state, so it logs the latest value of `count` after 4 seconds.
- `useEffect` *captures* the initial value of the `count` variable and logs the *captured* value instead of the latest value.

For in-depth explanation of the differences between `useEffect` and `componentDidMount`, i suggest you read following articles

- [useEffect(fn, []) is not the new componentDidMount()](https://reacttraining.com/blog/useEffect-is-not-the-new-componentDidMount/)
- [A Complete Guide to useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

---

**Coming back to your question**

If you paid attention to the first part of my answer that is related to your question, you probably now understand why `useEffect` runs its callback after both `First` and `Second` components have mounted.

If not, then let me explain.

After the execution of `useCustomHook` function that was called from within the `First` component, `First` component is mounted and if it was a class based component, its `componentDidMount` lifecycle function would have been called at this point.

After `First` component has mounted, `Second` component mounts and if this too was a class based component, its `componentDidMount` lifecycle function would have been called at this point.

After both components have mounted, browser paints the screen and as a result, you see the output on the screen. After the browser has painted the screen, callback function of the useEffect gets executed for both `First` and `Second` component.

In short, `useEffect` lets the browser paint the screen before running its effect/callback. That is why `useEffect gets called` is logged at at the end of the output.

You can see more details about this on official docs: [Timing of effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#timing-of-effects)

If you turn `First` and `Second` component in to class components, then output will be as:

```
1. component First rendering
2. component Second rendering
3. component First mounted.      // console.log statement inside componentDidMount
4. component Second mounted.     // console.log statement inside componentDidMount
```

You might expect 3rd line to be at 2nd place and 2nd line at 3rd place but that's not the case because react first executes the render functions of all the child components before they are inserted in the DOM and only after they are inserted in the DOM, `componentDidMount` of each component executes.

If you create `Third` and `Fourth` components and create following hierarchy of class components:

```
App
 |__ First
 |     |__ Third
 |          |__ Fourth
 | 
 |__ Second
```

then you will se the following output:

```
1.  First component constructor
2.  component First rendering
3.  Third component constructor
4.  component Third rendering
5.  Fourth component constructor
6.  component Fourth rendering
7.  Second component constructor
8.  component Second rendering
9.  component Fourth mounted
10. component Third mounted
11. component First mounted
12. component Second mounted
```

Comment: What is the difference b/w component mounting, component rendering, and browser painting the screen. Could you please explain.

Comment: see [React Mount vs Render](https://reacttraining.com/blog/mount-vs-render/#:~:text=Here's%20a%20brief%20tldr%3B,initial%20DOM%20from%20those%20instructions.) and [Browser Painting](https://css-tricks.com/browser-painting-and-considerations-for-web-performance/)

Comment: Thnks man,could you please help me with this question,it will be a great help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62285513/how-does-css-loader-resolve-resources-in-webpack/62287278#62287278

Answer (score 1):

The order that you have mentioned perfectly makes sense and thats how hooks works.

Flow:

- `First` component begins execution.
- In `First` component, after `useCustomHook(count)` line of code, the `useCustomHook` will be executed
- In `useCustomHook` the console.log is printed and the useEffect is executed and the CALLBACK that use effect takes is REGISTERED and NOT executed.
- `First` components returns JSX. i.e. component is mounted/rendered.
- Once `First` component is mounted, then the useEffect's callback in `useCustomHook` is called.
- Basically the `useCustomHook` inside the `First` component is scoped to the component.

Same goes with Second component as well...

Comment: But the First component should be rendered first and the useEffect callback should be called after that, but why is the Second component is getting called before that the useEffect callback by First component